# CsvHelper Ignore Complex Types

Tags: csvhelper

I'm trying to load test data from a CSV file into record that can be loaded into an In-Memory EF Core DB Context.

I have a Entity that simplified looks like:

```
public class Project
{
   public int { get; set; }
   public Owner? Owner { get; set; } = null;
}
```

A class Map:

```
public class ProjectsClassMap : CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap<Projects>
{
     public ProjectsClassMap()
     {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        Map(m => m.Owner).Ignore();

    }
}
```

Then a function to load data like so:

```
private void LoadTestData<T>(string fileName, InMemoryEFCoreDbContext db, Type? classMap = null)
            where T : class
        {
            var data = GetTestData(fileName);
            var readerConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) {
                Delimiter = ",",
                PrepareHeaderForMatch = (r, c) => r.Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToLower(),
                MissingFieldFound = (string[] values, int index, ReadingContext context) => { },
                ReadingExceptionOccurred = (ex) => false,
                HeaderValidated = (isValid, headerNames, headerNameIndex, context) => { },
                HasHeaderRecord = true,
                UseNewObjectForNullReferenceMembers = true,
            };
            if(classMap != null)
            {
                readerConfig.RegisterClassMap(classMap);
                readerConfig.IgnoreReferences = true;
            }
            
            using (var sReader = new StringReader(data))
            using (var csvReader = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(sReader, readerConfig))
            {
                var records = csvReader.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
                db.Set<T>().AddRange(records);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

The problem is that Owner is set to a new value instead of the default of null which causes validation errors while trying to save to DbContext.  How can I leave the complex reference type null rather than new?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```cs
public class ProjectsClassMap : CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap<Project>
{
    public ProjectsClassMap()
    {
        var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
        {
            IgnoreReferences = true
        };
        AutoMap(config);
    }
}
```

Update from @JoshClose

> The issue here is that AutoMap will set up all properties down the tree and ignoring that property doesn't remove all the properties on Owner.

Either use the `[Ignore]` attribute without `ProjectsClassMap` and `AutoMap` will set it up correctly.

```cs
public class Project
{
   public int { get; set; }
   [Ignore]
   public Owner? Owner { get; set; } = null;
}
```

Or if you need to use a class map, you'll have to manually remove the reference.

```cs
public class ProjectsClassMap : CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap<Project>
{
    public ProjectsClassMap()
    {   
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        ReferenceMaps.Remove(ReferenceMaps.Find<Project>(m => m.Owner));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that as well, but it doesn't work.  The only way I could get it to work was to make the reference type non-nullable.  Like public Owner Owner { get; set; } instead of public Owner? Owner { get; set; }

Comment: So is `Owner` not a class? Why do you need the "?"? Isn't a reference type nullable without that?

Comment: It's a feature of C# 8 to make nullability more explicit and easier to catch by the compiler.  By using Owner? you'd be telling the compiler that the value could be null

Comment: The issue here is that `AutoMap` will set up all properties down the tree and ignoring that property doesn't remove all the properties on `Owner`. If your `ClassMap` is that simple and you have control over the class, add an `[Ignore]` attribute to the `Owner` property and `AutoMap` will set it up correctly. If you don't have control and need to use a class map, you'll have to manually remove the reference `ReferenceMaps.Remove(ReferenceMaps.Find<Project>(m => m.Owner));`

Comment: @JoshClose I added your updates to the answer.  FYI, the first answer worked for me even with `public Owner? Owner { get; set; } = null;`

Comment: @JoshClose - Removing the ReferenceMap worked perfectly, thank you!  I did not try to use the [Ignore] attribute because I did not want to introduce dependencies.

Comment: @DavidSpecht Thanks again for all your answers!